# How to debug mbunit/Gallio unit tests in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, mbunit, gallio

I am trying to figure out how I can hit breakpoints in my unit tests that are written with MbUnit/Gallio. I tried running Gallio.Icarus, attaching vs debugger to it, the breakpoints weren't hit.
Next I tried to start Gallio.Echo from project properties, but I was getting an error message, after supplying the dll, saying only .exe's can be tested.
The unit test runs fine from Gallio.Icarus, however, I am unable to debug them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grab Gallio v3.0.6 Update 1.  Load up your tests and click on the shiny new "Debug" button in the Icarus GUI itself.

Answer (score 5):

I would use [TestDriven.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/) for this. It supports MbUnit tests, and you can debug by simply right clicking from within Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

A much better answer is found here:
[gallio test runner plugin to visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634665/gallio-test-runner-plugin-to-visual-studio-2008-and-2010-for-mbunit-tests)

The answer is to add the following section to your *.csproj file the after the <ProjectGuid> section section:

```
    <ProjectTypeGuids>
        {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}
      ; {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
    </ProjectTypeGuids>
```

See Also: 
[How Does Visual Studio Identiy test projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009943/how-does-visual-studio-mstest-identify-test-projects)
[A list of supported VS2010 project types](http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2009/09/visual-studio-projects-project-type.html) 
[Second list of GuIDs for supported project types](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx)