# Gallio test runner plugin to Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 for MBUnit tests

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, mbunit, gallio

If I install Gallio 3.x will it also install a test runner plugin for Visual Studio?

Or must I use an additional plug-in like TestDriven.NET or Visual Nunit to run MbUnit test classes from within VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestDriven.Net works really well.  Gallio also supports the ReSharper unit test runner and Visual Studio test tools.  We will be shipping a new release of Gallio this week with support for R# 5.0 and VS 2010.

Comment: Did Gallio v3.1 Update 2 build 397 - x86 have support for Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2? It's reason why Gallio tests don't work in OUTPUT window in VS 2010RC ? Will it change in new release you mention ?

Comment: Not having much luck with Icarus in 3.2 RC (build 577). It throws all sorts of exceptions in the UI.(Win7 32 bit) Is there any doc on how the integration with VS2010 actually works? I am using NUnit 2.5.3 but there are no context menus to run the tests etc.

Answer (score 19):

Install Gallio 3.1 on the dev machine. Then in VS2008, you'll have the option to create a "MbUnit v3 Test Project". This doesn't just include all of the Gallio dlls for you, it has a magic line in the project which identifies it to VS as a Test project.

You can now just use the in-built VS2008 Test runner.

If you have any existing projects with unit tests in, rather than making new projets, edit your existing project file and add the following line on line 9 (underneath the `<ProjectGuid>` on line 8):

```
 <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

(If you have a VB project, it has a different second GUID: `<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>` You can find the correct values by creating a new MbUnit test project from the templates installed with Gallio and then looking at the project file (.csproj or .vbproj) in a text editor.)

Now when you reload the project, VS2008 will recognise it as a test project.

A distinct advantage that I found over using Icarus was that debugging is now far more straight forward with break points being hit as expected.

Good Luck, Lee

Comment: I found this StackOverflow question's answer more than one year after it is written.. and it is still good. It works with VS2010 too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These are instruction for running MBUnit tests in Visual Studio 2012 and above using a neat NUnit trick.

Firstly, install the NUnit Test Adapter extension (yes, NUnit)

- Tools > Extension and Updates > Online > search for NUnit > install
  NUnit Test Adapter.
- You may need to restart the Visual Studio IDE.

Then, you simply need to add a new NUnit test attribute to your test methods. See example code here (notice the using statements at the top) ...

```
//C# example
using MbUnit.Framework;
using NuTest = NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute;

namespace MyTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Test, NuTest]
        public void myTest()
        {
            //this will pass
        }
    }
}
```

You can run and debug the test in visual studio as NUnit and Gallio Icarus GUI Test Runner will run them as MBUnit (enabling parallel runs for example).  You will need to stop Gallio from running the NUnit tests by deleting the NUnit folder in the gallio install location i.e. C:\Program Files\Gallio\bin\NUnit

Hope this helps, this is a simple working method so please vote up, many thanks.