# How does Visual Studio /mstest identify test projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

Say (100% hypothetically) that I've accidentally added a unit test project as project type "Class library" to a VS2010 solution. I've then added the assemblies needed to run it as a Unit Test project, but MSTest won't pick up on it when I hit "Run all tests in solution". What are the criterias here?

I had a couple of theories, which all have failed so far:

- Something in the .testsettings file (no references to any assemblies here as far as I can see)
- Something in the .SLN file (can't find anything)
- Something in AssemblyInfo.cs (no, it's not)
- Implict by referencing the (...)UnitTestFramwork.dll (Obv not)

Anyone?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the project file, there's an XML element with the name `ProjectTypeGuids`, that holds a few GUIDs that denote test project. Example as follows.

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Here's a list of known project type GUIDs for Visual Studio 2010: http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2009/09/visual-studio-projects-project-type.html

In the example above, it shows the project to be of type **Test** and **Windows (C#)**.

Comment: I found to get the flask icon, I also needed to add `<TestProjectType>UnitTest</TestProjectType>`

Comment: FWIW, this is still the case 10 years later with VS2019

Answer (score 4):

In case it helps anyone I had the opposite problem - I added a project as Unit Tests mistakenly. To change the type back to a normal Class Library I just removed the ProjectTypeGuids tags mentioned in the other answers altogether, presumably VS put back the correct ones.

Answer (score 3):

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project name and select **Unload Project**.
2. Then right-click the project name again and select **Edit ProjectName.csproj**.
3. Locate the **ProjectTypeGuids** element and following code.(If you will not find  the ProjectTypeGuids element, just insert it)

   `<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
   <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};
        {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
   </ProjectTypeGuids>
   </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>` 
   .
4. Save the changes, right-click the project, and then select **Reload** Project.