# How to change “Class Library Project” into “Test Project"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

While working on ASP.NET MVC3 application, by mistake I have added a **Class library as a Unit Test project**. But unfortunately I don’t see the "Run Tests" from context menu to test the methods which are created for unit testing .

Is there any way to convert the “Class Library Project” into a “Test Project” ?

Comment: You can add a new test project and compare the differences between the two project files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property type guid in the project file.
Look at this post: [How does Visual Studio /mstest identify test projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009943/how-does-visual-studio-mstest-identify-test-projects)

Comment: This is a link only answer.  Can you please put the actual fix in the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Just add `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` from nuget.

Comment: The guid ML were not relevant, just adding the package is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to do add this `<PropertyGroup>` tag with this `libraries` to my project (`.csproj` or `.vbproj`) file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

<!--Here goes any other configuration-->

</Project>
```