# MsTest in Visual Studio 2010 ignoring tests from a test assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

When I go to run the tests from a specific test assembly either by pressing Ctrl R + C or Ctrl R + T, Visual Studio decides to run all of the tests in solution.

When I run all of the tests in the solution, Visual Studio runs every test except the tests in this specific assembly.

Is there a way to persuade Visual Studio that the contents of this assembly are actually tests and that it should execute them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem, turns out it was because the project was marked as being a Windows assembly rather than a Windows assembly + test project. The method to transform a plain assembly into a test project is [documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009943/how-does-visual-studio-mstest-identify-test-projects)