# Unable to detect test cases Nunit, Specflow VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, specflow

I have following setup in my config file, but still the test explorer is not able to find the test cases.

```
<specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="Nunit" />
    <plugins>
      <add name="SpecFlow.Plus.Excel" type="Generator" />
    </plugins>
</specFlow>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't add the test adapter packages to your project.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38990326/3155323

You need a test runner adapter for Visual Studio to get the tests in the test explorer. They are distributed by NuGet packages. Add the package for your test runner to your test project.

- SpecFlow+Runner: SpecRun.Runner
- NUnit2: NUnitTestAdapter
- NUnit3: NUnit3TestAdapter
- XUnit: xunit.runner.visualstudio
- MsTest: no additional adapter needed

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **project** you have created and then make sure you do the following --
 1. Right click on your project
 2. Go to **Manage NuGet Packages **
 3. Go to **Installed** packages option & make sure you do have **NUnit Test Adaptor**